# Spring Integration is consuming more memory all the time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, memory-leaks, spring-integration

We have a Spring Boot app, with a Spring Integration context, consuming from ActiveMQ queues.

Without messages in the queues it's consuming more and more memory, and after several hours we always run out of memory.

It doesnt seem to do anything, but memory consumed ( heap ) is increasing constantly at a small pace.

How can we avoid this or at least profile this ?

Comment: Profile using Visual VM or dynaTrace.  Check your GC configuration.  Are you using JDK 8?  It matters.

Comment: yes, we are using Java 8, and we have profiled with VisualVM, JConsole, and now YourKit, but we can not see anything that could help

Comment: Check your GC settings on JVM.  Whose JVM?  Oracle, IBM, OpenJDK?

Comment: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.1) (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your code is not producing memory leaks?
If you connect to your app via Java VisualVM and see a picture like this:

[image: example of memory leak]

It's 100% that you have the exactly memory leak and this is not Spring or Java problem ;).

I can advise you read this useful articles how to debug such problems and after that investigate your app:

1. https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java
2. https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/memory-leaks/
3. https://dzone.com/articles/memory-leak-andjava-code
4. https://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/07/debugging-memory-leaks-with-visualvm/
5. http://blog.rejeev.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been using these JVM options since moving to JDK 8.  Perhaps they'll help your situation:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceExpansion=0 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -server -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256M -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
```

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.sokolenko.me/2014/11/javavm-options-production.html).  I found it very useful in tuning GC for JDK 8.

Comment: What I think is that GC arguments can help to have faster garbage collection, reduce CPU impact, etc..... But, if Spring is creating objects and have them adressed all the time, memory will exhaust at any time.

Comment: How can I know who is eating all the memory in Spring ? ( Btw, we are trying those arguments you sent , thank you )

Comment: I don't see why references aren't being cleaned up.  Static maps in code would be something to look for.

Comment: If you have an aggregator in your application, you need to expire groups. By default, a small group footprint is left to enable rejecting late arriving messages.

Comment: I have to say that playing with a poller is in fact affecting the memory foot print. I have modified the fixed_rate from 1ms to 100ms. 
Because with a heapdump it seems that **org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** is one the biggest consumers of memory